# C++ how to use modulus

Tags: c++, modulus

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ID,year;
    cout<<"Enter your ID";
    cin>>ID;

    year=
      cout<<"Year="<<year;


    system("pause");
}
```

`cin` example(20132724,20115555)

my question is how i can i make `Year` take the first 4 number(from left) from `ID`
by using the modulus.

Comment: You don't. You can get it through normal (integer) division though. You need modulo for the other field(s).

Answer (score 0):

Why use the modulus operator at all?

You should make your int into a string, take the first 4 characters, and make the resulting string back into an int

Comment: How is that better or easier than a simple integer division?

Comment: It doesn't require you to know the order of magnitude of the ID.. If the ID is 1.000.000, you have to divide by 1.000, but if it is 10.000.000 you have to divide by 10.000 to get the 4 most significant digits

Answer (score 0):

```
int ID_only = ID % 10000;  //ID only can be extracted like this
year = ID / 10000;        //this will get integer result not fraction
```

**Assumption:** your `ID` will be only 8 digits

Answer (score 0):

Think about modulus like this - it returns the remainder of division. In your case you have 20132724 for example. If you divide that number by 10000 you would get 2013.2724 and mod of that is whatever's after the period.

I would extract the first four numbers this way - since its already an int.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int ID, year;
    ID = 20132724;

    year = ID / 10000;
    std::cout << "Year = " << year; // since the type is int it 
                                    //wont print the fraction part
    return 0;
}
```